# DNS Spoof saves IP to Domain Name after attack is finished, Is there a way to stop this?

Tags: dns, apache, dns-spoofing

As I understand after a Domain Name is resolved to a specefic IP through DNS `www.example.com` resolves to `10.10.10.10`, this cache is saved in RAM in a computer for a little bit, AKA five or so minutes. (Note: Correct me if I'm wrong)

So, when I DNS spoof a computer to resolve `www.whatevs.com` to the IP of my website clone running on my local apache server: 192.168.1.5 . Then it does what it does and it is finished. But, the problem is after the attack is finished and I stop DNSSpoofing, the computer saves `www.whatevs.com` to `192.168.1.5` for a little while after, before it runs a DNS resolution lookup again to resolve the real IP. Does anyone know how to stop this by making the computer lose the cache, or forget `www.whatevs.com'`s fake IP address, so it must re-resolve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

DNS TTL is used to decide how long we want the entry to be cached on the local machine. Advertise smaller TTL (DNS server/Responder does this) so that the entry will be flushed at the configured time :-)

Try it out. Its fun.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the computer's *RAM*, its the DNS cache where this info is held, and it's held there till it expires. I believe the default (on Windows) is [1 day](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=dns%20cache%20default%20timeout).

To purge it earlier, run (on victim machine):

- Windows:  `ipconfig /flushdns`
- [Linux](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-debian-ubuntu-flush-clear-dns-cache/) (various, google for specific version)
- [OSX](https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-flush-dns-in-mac-os-x/) - `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache;sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`

*Note: Don't forget to purge the DNS cache on any upstream DNS Servers you may have poisoned as well, if necessary.*

Comment: Could I just set the TTL (Time To Live) to one second that way after they do the 'bad activity' the DNS is never cached, it must be re-resolved directly after?

Comment: In theory, but I would test it to be sure